# Table design for master data

Tags: database-design

I have an asp.net application that uses a lot of master data like Currencies, countries,cities and a lot of other domain specific master data. The current database model has one master table for each type of master data. For example countries have a separate master data table with an ID and a value column. Similary for all the other master data. Is this a right way to manage master data? I am open to completely change it. I would like to get some opinion on it. Also is there any articles or books that would prepare me for such scenarios in db modeling?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You're saying you have a tables like Countries, Currencies, Cities, etc, and they're essentially just key-value pairs, right?

Comment: @MattGrande . Yeah thats right. They mostly used to fill dropdown lists in the front end.

Comment: I would say that's fine then.  Keep doing that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In relational design and in data modeling, there's no such thing as "master" data, and there's no such thing as "master" tables. There's just data and tables.

So, if you need to store some kind of data about countries, even if it's just their names, then create a table of countries. Don't use an ID number, though. Use the [ISO country code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1). It's human-readable (for the most part) without requiring a join.  And make sure there's a unique constraint on the name, not just on the code. If you can have two countries named "Ireland", you've made a mistake.

Think carefully about who should be allowed to insert, update, and delete rows in that table. "Everyone" is almost certainly the wrong answer.

When other tables need to store the code for an existing country, those tables declare a foreign key to the table of countries.

If you're talking about a "master" table that looks like this . . .

```
ID    Name
--
1     England
2     London
3     Birmingham
4     Liverpool
5     British Pound (sterling)
6     Republic of Ireland
7     Aughagower
8     Ballyshannon
9     Euro
```

then you're creating worse problems that having a few more tables than you're comfortable with. The common name for this anti-pattern is "The One True Lookup Table".

First, foreign keys are useless here, since there's no way to present to the user a list of valid countries, cities, or currencies to choose from.  If the user simply selects values from this table, a user in London, England is liable to enter "Eury, Aughagower" instead.

Second, it's a factually incorrect model. "London" isn't a specify city's name; "London, England, UK", "London, Ontario, CA", and "London, Kentucky, USA" are, though.  If your database allows "cities" named "San Francisco, Alabama, USA", then you're not doing your job properly.

Third, that model isn't cleanly extensible. Currencies alone have more useful attributes than their name. The old British pound has a symbol, £, and an ISO code, GBP. I can't recall any report I've produced in the last 30 years that used the name of a currency instead of either its symbol or its ISO code.

Finally, modeling data correctly doesn't "pollute" the database, and there's no such thing as "mini-tables". Modeling data correctly simplifies your job, and it simplifies the application code. When you do a proper relational model, each table will store one and only one kind of fact.  If you have a problem, you'll know exactly where to look--SQL error messages almost always name the table that's causing the problem.  It's a lot easier to troubleshoot a problem with a table of countries than with a "master" table that might have 50 or more different kinds of facts stored in it.

If the number of tables is overwhelming, think about putting some of them in different schemas. As you gain experience, handling large numbers of well-named tables will become second nature, and you'll learn to ignore the tables that aren't relevant to your immediate task.

Comment: I saw many production software that uses Master Data Table (a big table that stores those Entities that only have "ID" and "Name" attributes). I found that the design is buggy but the other option polutes the Database Scheme with several mini-tables. So... is Master Data a Bad design practice?

Comment: @CarlosGavidia: Yes, "master" table is a bad design practice. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is justified to have a separate table for each *kind* of lookup data. This allows proper enforcement of referential integrity.

E.g. `COUNTRY_ID` field (in some "non-lookup" table) has a FOREIGN KEY referencing `COUNTRY` table, `CURRENCY_ID` references `CURRENCY` table etc... each field references the table appropriate for that particular field.